# How can I customize a select dropdown option

Tags: javascript, css, html

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfrmk8imwssqvu2/Screenshot%202015-08-20%2021.19.53.png?dl=0

I want to achieve the result given in this link. It is a 'Select' dropdown. How can I do that ?
I have searched for it but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Do you have some code for us?

Comment: please check the picture in the link. this is different matter.

Comment: Why are you people downgrading my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use bootstrap dropdown for [reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

Include bootstrap libraries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    // your content
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want fully customized layout in '<option>' of '<select>' tag

Comment: you can use bootstrap select.....